# Help with Shopping Cart Rule: Buy $200 worth of product use coupon code and get a product free

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I need help making a shopping cart rule.

If a customer buys **$200+ worth of product** and enters a **Coupon Code** they will **get a free Mug**. I only have a certain amount of Mugs to give away. I was hoping the customer wouldn't even have to put the Mug in their cart. Just use the code and then when we see the order on the back-end if they have used the Coupon Code we will add a Mug to their order.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution for you.

https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-buy-x-get-y-free

This is a free Magento plugin that should do what you need.

Use function
COUPON X
Use coupon X get product Y free, discounted.
You must also specify in your Coupon code the condition If "Subtotal" "is greater than" 199.99

I hope this helps,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a quick solution that doesn't require any customization or a third-party extension. You could always create a shopping-cart-price-rule where:

`Conditions: Subtotal equals or greater than 200`

`Actions: Apply "Fixed Amount Discount for Whole Cart", Discount Amount = "0.01"`

`Labels: Free Mug!`

Note - this won't auto-add the mug to the cart, you'll need an extension for that. You could give Amasty's Auto Add Promo Items extension a try - you can't go wrong with Amasty! https://amasty.com/auto-add-promo-items.html